# kubernetes dashboard kubernetes-dashboard-1.6.1.yaml behind firewall - image can't be pulled

Tags: kubernetes

Docker image has been loaded into docker from local image copy using:

```
docker load -i /var/images/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64

docker images|grep dash
```

*gcr.io/google_containers/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64      v1.6.1              71dfe833ce74        9 weeks ago         134.4 MB*

```
create -f /root/kubeadm-ha-master/kube-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard-1.6.1.yaml

grep image /root/kubeadm-ha-master/kube-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard-1.6.1.yaml
```

*image: gcr.io/google_containers/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64:v1.6.1*

```
kubectl logs kubernetes-dashboard-2209332821-cnt6k  -n kube-system
```

*Error from server (BadRequest): container "kubernetes-dashboard" in pod "kubernetes-dashboard-2209332821-cnt6k" is waiting to start: image can't be pulled*

I think that the image is attempting to be pulled from google instead of using the image already in docker.

Comment: Did you update `kubernetes-dashboard-1.6.1.yaml` file image tag with your local docker registry?

Answer (score 0):

Sorted - docker image was loaded only on the master node and not on the worker nodes. Of course the pod was getting deployed/placed on the worker nodes and was trying to pull image from google as image was not existing locally to the worker node.